# Error while open Web Analytics pages

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-analytics

When I'm trying to call the page of Web Analytics report from my local site I'm getting these logs, what can the problem be?

> 07/08/2015 00:12:00.36     w3wp.exe (0x0F50)                           0x1F1C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://ie-dev-sp57:7777/teams/opeportal/WebAnalyticsFiles/Report.aspx)    719055f1-93fb-493a-852c-02a4d8161aac
>
> 07/08/2015 00:12:00.38     w3wp.exe (0x0F50)                           0x1F1C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/teams/opeportal   719055f1-93fb-493a-852c-02a4d8161aac
>
> 07/08/2015 00:12:00.38     w3wp.exe (0x0F50)                           0x1F1C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (PostResolveRequestCacheHandler). Execution Time=10.249 719055f1-93fb-493a-852c-02a4d8161aac
>   07/08/2015 00:12:00.39  w3wp.exe (0x0F50)                           0x1F1C  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPageUserException: The dynamicmasterpagefile attribute on the page directive is not allowed in this page.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter.PreprocessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary attributes)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)   719055f1-93fb-493a-852c-02a4d8161aac
>
> 07/08/2015 00:12:00.39     w3wp.exe (0x0F50)                           0x1F1C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://ie-dev-sp57:7777/teams/opeportal/WebAnalyticsFiles/Report.aspx)). Execution Time=28.2858   719055f1-93fb-493a-852c-02a4d8161aac

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem too on a single site collection. I have read advice on some forum and simply went to the site collection settings and turned off reporting and turned it on again.

Analytics went back to work again.